# Dimensioning a redis set

Tags: memory, redis, dimension

We want to use redis for one of our data stores. We have a hard time "guessing" what the size of that redis store will be and we're hoping someone can come up with the right help.

This store will exclusively be be built using [Sorted Sets](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set). Each set will have a key that will be an integer between 1 and 10^10. We currently have about 8M keys, but we expect to reach 30M 'quickly'.

Each set will have a variable number of elements, but the average is 17 elements, with a max of 135 and a min of 0. (Let me know if we need to provide other numbers, like st. dev.).

The elements in the sorted set will be strings. Now we want them to be the shortest string possible (5 or 6 chars?), but still avoid collisions. The scores will be timestamps.

We currently have about 500 writes/sec, but expect to grow that 10 times, and we currently have 3000 reads/sec and expect to grow that also 10 times.

We will also use the "dump" strategy rather than AOF.

Our goal is to use a single (yet big) Redis master store (and maybe some slaves store). What RAM should we allocate to our redis instance?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Redis 2.6, you can benefit from the ziplist memory optimization applied to zset, because most of your zsets have a small number of items.

To calculate the memory you need, you can simply fill an instance with a small number of keys corresponding to your requirements and extrapolate. For this use case, memory consumption will grow linearly with the number of keys.

I have just tried it on my system, I get 30 MB per 100000 keys (following your specifications), which results in 9 GB of memory required for 30M keys. You need to take some margin, and include some space for COW memory spent at save time.

A 12 GB server would probably work if you are careful.
A 16 GB server will be just fine.

Comment: Thanks Didier! I have done tests myself in the meantime, and I roughly have the same numbers! Thanks a lot!